# Parsing a stringified OrderedDictionary in Python

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I have a need to change one of my dictionaries from a normal `dict` to a `collections.OrderedDict`. The problem is that I store my dictionary as a string in an object that I need to later extract. Call my `dict` object `foo`. My previous method of doing this was:

```
storedDict = str(foo)
```

Then in another file:

```
import ast
parsedDict = ast.literal_eval(storedDict)
```

This works all fine and dandy, but now that I have changed `foo` to be an `OrderedDict`, it can no longer be parsed by the `ast.literal_eval` function. Is there a function or good method I can use to parse a stringified `OrderedDict`? I am trying to avoid serialization here to stay consistent with the rest of the program.

Comment: You may want to consider passing it through JSON instead then.

Comment: You're trying to avoid serialization but you said yourself you stringified your dict. Why are you doing all this? None of this sounds like a good idea and I think you're just causing yourself headaches (like this question) by solving some earlier problem the wrong way.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist by avoiding serialization I meant avoiding using a pickler/unpickler, I should have clarified. This is because I am working on a project written by someone else and they did everything simply by storing things as strings and then parsing them later.

Comment: @samalamma708 I assumed that's what you meant, but distinguishing between simple stringification and `pickle` is silly in this context. One is just a more robust serialization than the other. The fact is you are _embroiled_ in serialization because of the way your inherited codebase is designed (which, as a side note, I'm very sorry to hear about). Because of this, I don't think introducing `pickle` is really bad or inconsistent, from the sounds of it. However, you could also consider dropping `OrderedDict` and simply stringifying the keys separately, then pulling them out in order.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the easiest way is to write your own serializer for it; especially because it's an *ordered* dict, so you want to keep the order, I assume.

It could be as simple as this (assuming your keys and values are simple:

```
buf = ""
for k, v in myOrderedDict.iteritems():
    buf += k + "\t" + v + "\n"
print(buf)
```

If the data can be more complicated, you can escape or quote as needed.

Then when you want it back:

```
d = ordereddict()
while(True):
    r = readline()
    k, v = r.split('\t')
    d[k] = v
```